# Laptop unable to resume after suspend [Juno on Asus A54C, i3 2.2ghz, 8gb ram, SSD]

Tags: suspend, laptop, release-juno, asus

If the computer goes into suspend, through the power button, closing the lid, or inactivity, I cannot get it to come back to life. My only recourse is to power cycle the laptop.

I am unsure where to start looking for problems.  I am having a couple other minor issues, they may be related, I am not certain.

I have a few PPAs, but the problem has been since the initial install.

Other than this problem, it has been working really well.  I don't want to have to reinstall the os or format anything.

Comment: It might help if you provide some info on what occurs when you attempt to resume from a suspend. (E.g., "keyboard lighting turns comes on, but screen never lights up," or "screen backlight illuminates, but screen remains black.")